# Unable to mount share from machine to Ubuntu VM as a guest using SMB (Able with AFP)

Tags: networking, server, mount, windows, samba

I am trying to connect through SMB and AFP from an ubuntu 17.10 VM image to a machine accessible from my network which has both AFP and SMB enable.

I have tried to connect from both ubuntu terminal and the file explorer.
It seems that I can mount the share using AFP and see the files from the share.

I get a timeout when I try to connect using SMB. Please note that I also can't connect from my windows machine to that machine using SMB.

I have checked and I can ping it also without any issue and I have created the `/mnt/ths_mtn` and gave them 777 priviledges with `chmod`.

This is how I am trying to connect from terminal:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //172.16.20.110/Shared /mnt/ths_mnt -o username="guest",password=""
```

and from ubuntu file explorer:

```
smb://172.16.20.110/Shared/
```

Error from terminal:

```
mount: /mnt/ths_mnt: mount(2) system call failed: Operation now in
progress.
```

Error from explorer:

```
Failed to mount Windows share: Connection timed out.
```

I have checked that the smb config file allows connections from guest users.

What the problem might be? is there any other configurations I could change to make this work?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the problem was. Syslog and samba logs didn't help me understand what's wrong, only that it is continuously trying to connect but fails. And this happens to both Windows and Ubuntu in VirtualBox.

I have disconnected wifi and I am now connecting through Ethernet and it works. I am pleased that I can connect now, but fixing this issue using wifi would be much better! So if anyone has any ideas on what the problem might be, please let me know.